# How can I get all transactions made by an account?

Tags: transactions, blocks

I tried this history api of this function :

```
func (api *API) GetTransactions(name AccountName) (out *TransactionsResp, err error) {
    err = api.call("account_history", "get_transactions", M{"account_name": name}, &out)
    return
}
```

but it doesn't work on test net. Is there any way I can get a list of transactions pushed by an account?

Comment: In many searches i found that this don't work for test net, So how can I test my actions if it work on main net?